# How to make Swift JSON request params

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

I got a problem with making a request to a server, I got a parsing error, could you help me to make the request properly?

**I need to make a request like this:**

```
"{ \"jsonrpc\": \"2.0\", \"id\": 1, \"method\": \"call\", \"params\": [ \"c36c5a835cf88e82f97dcfa5b74f53f4\",\"network.interface.wan\",\"status\", {} ] }"
```

**My request:**

```
["jsonrpc": "2.0", "id": 1, "method": "call", "params": [token, "network.interface.wan", "status", []]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to convert `Dictionary` as `JSON` String response then you can try like this way.

**Edit:** In JSON string with `params` array the last object is empty dictionary so you need to set last object of params array as `[:]` instead of `[]`

```
let dic:[String:Any] = [
                            "jsonrpc": "2.0",
                            "id": 1,
                            "method": "call",
                            "params": [
                                            "token",
                                            "network.interface.wan",
                                            "status", [:]
                            ]
                        ]
if let data = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic),
    let string = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8){
    print(string)
}
```

**Output**

```
{\"method\":\"call\",\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"id\":1,\"params\":[\"token\",\"network.interface.wan\",\"status\",{}]}
```